# Retornar quantidade de dependentes por colaborador

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select, count

Eu preciso selecionar a Chapa, o Nome do Colaborador e a Quantidade de Dependentes de cada Colaborador, porém o resultado dessa consulta está mostrando a quantidade de dependentes apenas para o primeiro colaborador, e eu preciso das quantidades para todos os colaboradores.

Obs.: Se retirar a clausula `WHERE`, a consulta mostra a quantidade de todos os dependentes da tabela dependente apenas do primeiro colaborador.

Tabelas: COLABORADOR e DEPENDENTE

```
SELECT C.CHAPA, C.NOMECOLABORADOR,
    COUNT(D.NOMEDEP) AS QNT_DEP 
    FROM COLABORADOR C, DEPENDENTE D
    WHERE D.CHAPA=C.CHAPA;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do jeito que você está fazendo a consulta, a função `COUNT()` fará uma contagem de todos os registros retornados.

Entretanto, você quer fazer a contagem de dependentes para cada colaborador, logo, você precisa agrupar os resultados com a cláusula `GROUP BY`. Dessa forma a função `COUNT()` contará os dependentes dentro daquele grupo definido, ao invés de todos os registros retornados.

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT C.CHAPA, C.NOMECOLABORADOR, COUNT(D.NOMEDEP) AS QNT_DEP 
FROM COLABORADOR C, DEPENDENTE D
WHERE D.CHAPA = C.CHAPA
GROUP BY C.CHAPA, C.NOMECOLABORADOR;
```

Essa é a forma ditada pelo padrão SQL92 (revisão da linguagem SQL), que diz que os campos que aparecem na cláusula `SELECT` devem aparecer também na cláusula `GROUP BY`, se ela existir. Mas o MySQL pode seguir o padrão SQL99, dependendo de como esteja configurado ([documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)), e aí você poderia usar só o campo `CHAPA` para fazer o agrupamento:

```
SELECT C.CHAPA, C.NOMECOLABORADOR, COUNT(D.NOMEDEP) AS QNT_DEP 
FROM COLABORADOR C, DEPENDENTE D
WHERE D.CHAPA = C.CHAPA
GROUP BY C.CHAPA;
```